# how to customize the layout of the facebook registration plugin error messages

Tags: facebook, plugins, customization, registration

I was wandering if is it possible to customize the facebook registration plugin layout.

In particolar i'm trying to customize the layout of the error messages.

Example: the default error message for the incorrect password is a "**custom message**" with some default properties (red color, font, width, heigth, etc etc).

How can i show a (for example) green error message ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the CSS used by the registration plugin. You can try to overwrite the CSS by using the same CSS class names the plugin is using and replacing the attributes you want to modify, but its not guaranteed to work.